# Form submit value giving null - mongoose and express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to make a way to send data from a basic html form to mongodb using express. but it's giving me null when I post it.

I used the following Schema : commentname: String.

Here's the HTML:

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="textbox" id="cmt-1" placeholder="comment here"/>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="submit()" class="submit">
  submit
</button>
```

JS:

```js
var cmt = document.getElementById('cmt-1').value;
var comment = {commentname: ''};
comment = {commentname: cmt};

function submit () {
  async function postData (url = '', data = {}) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'same-origin',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    });
    return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
  }

  postData(
    'https://realtime-comt-system-100.glitch.me/comments/add',{comment}
  )
  .then(data => { console.log(data); });
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this code but check the url i put . don't put the whole url just put the path name .
also take this code copy and paste , the html and the java script take them both because i changed both of them

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');


form.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let cmt = form.cmt.value;
let data = {commentname: cmt};

 const response = await fetch('/comments/add', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
      
      }).then(res =>{
      console.log(res)
      }).catch(err){
      console.error(err)
      }
    
    })
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="textbox" id="cmt-1" name='cmt' placeholder="comment here"/>
</form>
<button type="submit" onclick="submit()" class="submit">
  submit
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a bit change to `cmt= form.cmt.value` and made it `cmt=document.getElementById(cmt-1).value` and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not being caused by the code posted above.

It's a Mongoose problem. You are trying to create two documents with the same id, when that id has been specified unique to Mongoose.

This is what the code is posting in the body to the backend, a JSON string:

```sh
{"comment":{"commentname":"my sample comment"}}
```

The fact that you're posting an object inside an object looks suspicious. This pattern would be more common:

```sh
{"commentname":"my sample comment"}
```

But since there is no backend code posted, it's impossible to tell if this is correct.

When I tried posting `{"comment":{"commentname":"my sample comment"}}` to the backend URL using Postman, I received the following response code:

```sh
400 Bad Request
```

The response body:

```sh
"Error: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: database.comments index: commentname_1 dup key: { commentname: null }"
```

From [Mastering JS - Debug E11000 Errors in Mongoose](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/e11000-duplicate-key)

> MongoDB's E11000 error is a common source of confusion. This error occurs when ***two documents have the same value for a field that's defined as unique*** in your Mongoose schema.
>
> Mongoose models have an _id field that's always unique.